# Will profile for Express Entry frozen after the ITA?

Tags: express-entry

So apparently one can change the profile for express entry Canada as per their [website](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1005&top=29). Now, If I want to update my experience years, when is the latest I can change it?

If I receive ITA will I still be able to change the job dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to update your profile once you receive an invitation to apply.

However, when you get an invitation and submit the application for permanent residence, you will be asked to update all your information and a CRS score will be calculated on the day of submission, which will be the determining score for your application. IRCC addresses the considerations for changes in circumstances on [their website here](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/permanent-residence/express-entry/assessing-electronic-application-on-section-a11-2.html).

Comment: Assuming that my CRS score is above the cuttoff for given round, will I be given ITA immediately or will I be randomly selected from the list of people above the cutoff?

Comment: @user0193 The cutoff is determined by the score of the lowest ranked eligible candidate in that round. You will be issued an ITA if your score is above the cutoff and you meet other requirements of that round of invitations (e.g. belonging to a particular class or stream).

Comment: well federal skills trade FST is anticipated to have cutoff of 471 when ever the round opens, so assuming that candidate has 472, will he/she automatically get the ITA or still have to wait for selection in other rounds?

Comment: @user0193 i wouldn't put too much faith in the anticipated score. The government does not have a score in mind, they decide the number of people they want to invite and then use the score of the lowest ranked candidate within the target number to obtain the cutoff. Your rank matters, not your score, the cutoff is just to give you an idea. If you qualify for the federal skilled trades program, the cutoff is 471 and you have 472 points, you will receive an invitation.

Comment: Awsome! This makes sense!